# I want to make reply control on the Reply button click

Tags: c#, javascript

I wan to create reply control for the web site in which 
if user click on the Reply button then he or she get textbox and button and after clicking on that button the textbox value is insert to the DataBase

I already write one script 
the script is like this

Click me!

but this script give me textbox for the 2 to 3 second and after page post back the textbox and button is disappear

so some body help if its possible

Answer (score 0):

You should disable the AutoPostBack property (not sure on the name by heart) on the button which calls your script.

This way, your button will only perform it's action on client-side, and not refresh the page.

Comment: after disable the AutoPostBack property it also not work properly 
If i am disable auto post back property how can i got that particular file name for the inserting it to the database ??????????

Comment: Well I'm not sure, haven't made any asp.net page for years, but there _must_ be a way for you to tell the page that it should post its values.
So, when the user has entered the needed values (I'm assuming that now your form is displaying correctly?), you could use a "submit" button, which would have the AutoPostBack value set to "true", and do the treatment in the reloaded page.  Hope this will help you to find the answer :-)